# Does an alternative exist to the z-index bug in Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

It doesn't matter how high I set the z-index, or if I set `position:relative;` to the parent div, or if I set a higher z-index to parent `div` or any tweak I found in Google.

My tooltip will not be visible in Internet Explorer 7,

Is there any other property I could use to simulate z-index positioning?

Comment: Hard to tell without showing us some code / a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: you can check at http://jsfiddle.net/qYNXa/ there are no images, but if you click on the phone number on the top right you will see the dropdown (#callCenter) over a black area where normally is a bg-image wich stays ontop in IE7 so the dropdown is not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the tooltip being positioned? Try adding `position:absolute; z-index:999` to your tooltip div and `position:relative` to the parent to see how it reacts.

It would be really helpful if you can post your page or some code.

Comment: The tooltip is absolute already and as i comment in the question; position:relative for the parent is not helping.. :(

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page so we can take a look?

Comment: So where is the tooltip located?

Comment: I may have found your issue, you have an overlay div with some opacity added that is covering up your tooltip, it is this class "contTitHtlGold", if you remove the "position:relative" style from that class the tooptip should show up.

Comment: please check my only comment in the original questin answering @PeeHaa thanks!

Comment: if i use that it cracks FF so i think i'll use it but as a hack, what do you think?!!!

Comment: You could add a conditional comment to the head of your page to target only ie that sets the position of that div to static, like so: <!--[if IE 7]>
        .contTitHtlGold { position:static; }
<![endif]-->  ..... or you can just add another line right below that with an asterisk in the beginning, like so "position:relative; * position: static;" that should target ie as well

Comment: your second option was my solution, so like this it stays: total_hours_wasted_here = 5 (hahaha)

Comment: Hey, it happens :P ..im glad you got your issue fixed.

Comment: buddy, now the position:static hides the container http://goo.gl/hAfgk (please check in FF or IE7 to see what I mean), any idea?

Comment: Im looking at the site, where do i see the tooltip? Linda pagina :P

Comment: the tooltip is hidden behind the landscape image :(

Comment: Right, but what do i click to bring it up?

Comment: same that in jsdfiddle; the phone number :D

Comment: Saw it, the problem is not the css there its your javascript :P ..if you take a look at the box in Chromes developer tools or firebug in FF you can see that when you click the phone number the "display:none" on the box doesnt change, so it doesnt come up. Make sure that your js is ok.

Comment: Just took a look at your css in IE8 browser with the developers tools at work, once you click the phone number number the "display:none" style is not being toggled on the "#callCenter" id, also, in IE, the tooltip is appearing behind everything else due to the ".contTitHtlGold" class having an opacity style to it, if you remove that it comes up fine, also on the same class raise the z-index level from 1 to 9999 to bring in the tooltip on top of everything else. Here is a screenshot, http://i.imgur.com/eqiZL.jpg  ..it should be the same for IE7.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative I tend to use is adding the dropdown menu right after `<body id="homeIsoraGold" class="idioma_es">`.

And then positioning it with JavaScript to be placed where you want it.

Because it is placed right after the body it will already be high in the DOM (tree) so you will have the best chance of it being on top.

Comment: Hey! thanks for your time and idea; but i don't think that is going to be posible unless i can do that vía javascript/jquery: i can't edit the HTML :(